# Condition in a list and way to extract

Tags: python, list, conditional-statements

I would like to know how to extract an sub list which contains only increasing numbers. 
This is what I have done for now and it is actually working :

```
def psiListe(L):
    J,max,beg,end=[],0,0,0
    for k in range(len(L)-1):
        i=0
        K=[L[k]]
        while L[i+k]<L[i+k+1] and k+i<=len(L):
            i+=1
            K=K+[L[k+i]]
        if len(K)>max:
            J,max,beg,end=K,len(K),k,i
    return (J,beg,end)
```

I would like to extract every increasing sub list in one line like that :

```
    J=[ [L[i] for i in range(k+1,len(L)) if L[i]>L[i-1] else break] for k in range(len(L))]
```

but that line does not work. The problem is in the condition but i have no idea why it is an invalid synthax.

Comment: I would strongly recommend against doing this as it's extremely difficult to read.

Comment: You should declare your integer variable in that statement, `for i in range`.

Comment: i agree it is not easy to read but i'm interrested to know why it behave like that and not the way I want it to work.

Comment: do you have a variable name called: `Len` or it was an error while you were typing? ---> `...range(k+1,Len(L))...`

Comment: an other error while copying the line sorry

Comment: @estebanpdl `len(L)` is a python function which gives back the length of the list `L`, it is not a variable.

Comment: `break`s are illegal in list comprehensions

Comment: @ImtiazRaqib I know what it is, but code example had `Len` instead `len`. I was making some proofs with random numbers. That's why.

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski that is why, thank you for you answer. Is there away to do the same things in list comprehension ?